# how to auto increament id field by 1 in text box?

Tags: python-2.7, django-templates

i want to auto increament for car_id field which is primary key but after saving registration data the car_id field should automaticaly increament so please anyone can suggest me for this.and my code is as follow.

models.py

```
class car(models.Model):

car_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=400, primary_key=True)
plate_no = models.IntegerField(max_length=400)
brand = models.CharField(max_length=400)
model = models.CharField(max_length=400)
Condition = models.CharField(max_length=400)
daily_price = models.IntegerField()
def __str__(self):
    return ' '.join([
        self. ordering,

    ])
```

views.py

```
def display_car(request):
carid_query = car.objects.values('car_id')
plate = car.objects.values('plate_no')
brand = car.objects.values('brand')
model = car.objects.values('model')
price = car.objects.values('daily_price')
condition = car.objects.values('Condition')
query_all = car.objects.all()
data={
    'carid_query': carid_query,
    'plate': plate,
    'brand': brand,
    'model': model,
    'price': price,
    'condition': condition,
    'query_all': query_all,


}
return render(request, 'view_car.html', data)
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="center">
<a href="/login_auth/">Home</a>&nbsp&nbsp;<a href="/car">Car Registration</a>&nbsp&nbsp;<a href="/car_link/">Rent</a>
</div>
<form action="/car/" id="form_id" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}


<div id="head_div">
<h3>car Registration</h3></div>
<table class="center">
<tr><td>
Car_id:<input type="text" name="car_id"><td>

<td>plate no:<input type="text" id="plate_id" name="plate_id"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Brand:<input type="text" id="brand_id" name="brand_id"><td>
<td>Model:<input type="text" name="model_id"></td></tr>
<tr><td>
Daily Price:<input type="text" id="price_id" name="price_id"></td>
<td>
Condition:<select name="select_id"><option value="Good">simple</option>
                                <option value="middle">A/C</option>
                                <option value="bad">good</option></select></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="submit" id="sub_id" onclick="demo(this.form)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="cancel_id" VALUE="Cancel"></td>
</tr>
</table>


</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but your auto-incrment feature should be within your DBMS, not your server-side code.

Comment: it means no need to apply logic into views.py or javascript

Comment: So you should, as I advised, let your DBMS handle the auto-increment... but maybe I missed the point, I must admit I'm not into Python myself...